# Filling gaps in a group by query

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a table in SQL Server that stores date, db and number of incidents (`CreateDate`,`DB_Name`,`Incident`) that I can aggregate by grouping into something like the following:

```
[CreateDate]  [DB_Name] [Count of Incidents]
20140214      tempdb       10  
20140215      tempdb       9  
20140217      tempdb       8
20140215      msdb         10    
20140218      msdb         11
```

but want (for graphing and stats) this:

```
[CreateDate]  [DB_Name] [Count of Incidents]
20140214      tempdb       10  
20140215      tempdb       9  
20140216      tempdb       0  
20140217      tempdb       8
20140218      tempdb       0  
20140214      msdb         0    
20140215      msdb         10    
20140216      msdb         0    
20140217      msdb         0    
20140218      msdb         11
```

I would like to put this in a view.  I've tried CTE's but have not looked at "applys".

Cheers and thanks for the help/suggestions.

Comment: There should be a crlf to break this into two lines20140217 tempdb 8 20140218 tempdb 0

Comment: You just need to use a calendar table and a lookup table for the DBs, then `LEFT JOIN` your counts

Comment: Do you have a calendar table?

Comment: Join to a calendar table. There are about 50 examples of how to make one online and they will make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment that a calendar table can make your life a lot easier as it can be used for many purposes across your databases, but if you want to create a view using only the provided information here is a recursive CTE solution.

```
/*
--      Create Base Table
If      Object_ID('GappedHistory') Is Not Null Drop Table GappedHistory;
Create  Table GappedHistory (CreateDate Date, DBName Varchar(50), CntOfIncidents Int);
Insert  GappedHistory (CreateDate, DBName, CntOfIncidents)
Values  ('2014-02-14', 'tempdb', 10),
        ('2014-02-15', 'tempdb', 9),
        ('2014-02-17', 'tempdb', 8),
        ('2014-02-15', 'msdb', 10),
        ('2014-02-18', 'msdb', 11);
Go
*/

--      Build the view
Create  View vwAllDatesResults
As
With    dates As
(
        Select  Distinct
                DBName, 
                Min(CreateDate) Over (Order By CreateDate) As rangeDates,
                Max(CreateDate) Over (Order By CreateDate Desc) As maxCreateDate
        From    GappedHistory g
        Union   All
        Select  DBName,
                DateAdd(Day,1,rangeDates),
                maxCreateDate
        From    dates
        Where   rangeDates < maxCreateDate      
),      recurCTE As
(
        Select  IsNull(g.CreateDate, m.rangeDates) As CreateDate,
                IsNull(g.DBName, m.DBName) As DBName,
                IsNull(g.CntOfIncidents,0) As CntOfIncidents
        From    GappedHistory g
        Full    Outer Join dates m
                On  g.CreateDate = m.rangeDates
                And g.DBName = m.DBName
)
Select  *
From    recurCTE
Go

--      Query the view
Select  *
From    vwAllDatesResults
Order   By DBName Desc, CreateDate
```